# Finding source repository for any command

Tags: debian, apt-get

If I wanted to get the source for a particular command, for example, /sbin/shutdown.  How would I go about finding which repo to add /etc/apt/sources.list and then how would I use apt to retrieve the code?

I know to retrieve the code, i can use "sudo apt-get source ???" but I can't find any resources on getting from /sbin/shutdown to the ???.

*Enviroment: I'm using Debian Squeeze and kernel 2.6.32.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debian.org website has a tool to search for packages containing a given file:

For example, for your shutdown command:

http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=shutdown&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any

This gives you a list of packages for which you can get the source.

Hope this help!

Comment: Interesting, I used that search and found the sources for coreutils. Learning more about the Linux OS every day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [apt-file](http://packages.qa.debian.org/a/apt-file.html) locally. You need to create a cache first by running `apt-file update`.  This has the (minor) advantage of not requiring network access for the search.

```
apt-file search  /sbin/shutdown
 molly-guard: /usr/sbin/shutdown
 systemd-sysv: /sbin/shutdown
 sysvinit: /sbin/shutdown
 upstart: /sbin/shutdown
```

Then you could use eg. packages.qa.debian.org/upstart to see all the information about the horse, though normally you can just do

```
apt-get install whatever
```